# Plot Joint Probability Density Function

Tags: python, scipy

How can I plot the joint probability density function of 2 random variables (the means and variances of the random variables are given) in Python?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at the [Seaborn jointplot](http://stanford.edu/~mwaskom/software/seaborn/generated/seaborn.jointplot.html).