# Plotting joint probability of two random variable choices

Tags: python, matplotlib, random, statistics, seaborn

If I have two variables, say

```
x = random.choices([0.25, 0.75], [25, 75])
y = random.choices([0.4, 0.6], [4, 6])
```

how can I plot a 2D chart of with x-axis between 0 and 1, and y-axis between 0 and 1, to show the multiplied probabilities of the two variables, in a heatmap style format?

Thank you

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Plot Joint Probability Density Function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36119400/plot-joint-probability-density-function)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a `pandas.DataFrame` in which each line is a sample of the population, then you can plot the joint probability with [`seaborn.jointplot`](http://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.jointplot.html).
You can play with `kind` parameter to customize the type of plot you want.

### Complete Code

```
import random
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

n_samples = 100

x = random.choices(population = [0.25, 0.75], weights = [25, 75], k = n_samples)
y = random.choices(population = [0.4, 0.6], weights = [4, 6], k = n_samples)

df = pd.DataFrame({'x': x, 'y': y})

sns.jointplot(data = df, x = 'x', y = 'y', kind = 'kde', xlim = (0, 1), ylim = (0, 1))

plt.show()
```

- `kind = 'kde'`

  [image]
- `kind = 'hist'`

[image]